# screenshot of specific dom element using ruby

Tags: ruby, capybara, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a way to do [this](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.captureSelector) using capybara+phantomjs.

Or perhaps something more complex like cropping a full page screenshot to the specific dom element?

Comment: [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) the Capybara driver for PhantomJS nearly has what you're asking but not quite. If you're willing to fill the gap yourself you can try and hack the [render binding](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/blob/98d4a4a8936e8d6b3417f2c057bafaba40874eee/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/browser.js#L285) to pass the coordinates of the element you're interested in to the setClipRect() setter which dictates the area to be captured.

Comment: Using Poltergeist + some JS you could try the following.

First using JS select the DOM element you desire and store it in a variable. You can then empty the body tag of the document using JS and then fill it with your DOM element.

Then take a screenshot using the poltergeist driver.

If you have CSS rules that have to stay you could first hide all other elements using JS and then take the screenshot.

Comment: A pull request has been submitted for this feature, and will be closed shortly.

Answer (score 1):

A [pull request](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/pull/368) has been submitted for this feature.

It will be closed shortly, and you will be able to use

```
driver.render selector: '#some_id`
```

in the next release.

Comment: Well, did it save the file to?